# Запятая в придаточном

Tags: пунктуация

"которую понимаешь ты и которая понимает тебя" - тут не  нужна запятая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"которую понимаешь ты и которая понимает тебя"

Хорошо бы всё предложение посмотреть. Но, скорее всего, это два однородных равноправных придаточных определительных предложения, которые относятся к одному главному. Между ними сочинительная связь, поэтому запятая перед И не нужна.
 Например, встретил женщину (какую?) которую понимаешь ты;  встретил женщину (какую?) которая понимает тебя.